# spark with column and aggregate function dropping other columns in the dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below data frame and I have grouped the below data frame by `id`, `txnId` and `date`

```
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+------+------+
|       id|         txnId|account|        date|      idl|  type|amount|
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+------+------+
|      153|   0000004512 |  30095|    11272020|       30| debit|  1000|
|      153|   0000004512 |  30096|    11272020|        0|credit|   200|
|      145|   0000004513 |  30095|    11272020|        0| debit|  4000|
|      135|   0000004512 |  30096|    11272020|        0|credit|  2000|
|      153|   0000004512 |  30097|    11272020|        0| debit|  1000|
|      145|   0000004514 |  30094|    11272020|        0| debit|  1000|
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+------+------+
```

so after grouping , the output is

```
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+------+------+
|       id|         txnId|account|        date|      idl|  type|amount|
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+------+------+
|      153|    0000004512|  30095|    11272020|       30| debit|  1000|
|      153|    0000004512|  30096|    11272020|        0|credit|   200|
|      153|    0000004512|  30097|    11272020|        0| debit|  1000|
|      153|    0000004512|  30097|    11272020|        0|credit|   500|
|      145|    0000004513|  30095|    11272020|        0| debit|  4000|
|      145|    0000004514|  30094|    11272020|        0| debit|  1000|
|      135|    0000004512|  30096|    11272020|        0|credit|  2000|
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+------+------+
```

I need to add a third and fourth column to the data frame such that it is a total of amounts by the type credit or debit for that group , the output should look like

```
+---------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------+------+-----------+----------+
|       id|         txnId|account|       date|      idl|  type|amount|totalcredit|totaldebit|
+---------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------+------+-----------+----------+
|      153|    0000004512|  30095|   11272020|       30| debit|  1000|          0|      2000|
|      153|    0000004512|  30096|   11272020|        0|credit|   200|        700|         0|
|      153|    0000004512|  30097|   11272020|        0| debit|  1000|          0|      2000|
|      153|    0000004512|  30097|   11272020|        0|credit|   500|        700|         0|
|      145|    0000004513|  30095|   11272020|        0| debit|  4000|          0|      4000|
|      145|    0000004514|  30094|   11272020|        0|credit|  1000|       1000|         0|
|      135|    0000004512|  30096|   11272020|        0|credit|  2000|       2000|         0|
+---------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------+------+-----------+----------+
```

I have written the below code to add new column for

```java
Dataset <Row> df3 = df2.where(df2.col("type").equalTo("credit"))
    .groupBy("type")
    .agg(sum("amount")).withColumnRenamed("sum(amount)", "totalcredit");
```

but it is dropping the other columns from the dataset, how do I preserve the other columns in the dataset ?.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use conditional sum aggregation over a Window partitioned by `id`:

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;


WindowSpec w = Window.partitionBy("id");

Dataset <Row> df3 = df2.withColumn(
    "totalcredit",
    when(
        col("type").equalTo("credit"),
        sum(when(col("type").equalTo("credit"), col("amount"))).over(w)
    ).otherwise(0)
).withColumn(
    "totaldebit",
    when(
        col("type").equalTo("debit"),
        sum(when(col("type").equalTo("debit"), col("amount"))).over(w)
    ).otherwise(0)
);


df3.show();

//+---+-----+-------+--------+---+------+------+-----------+----------+
//| id|txnId|account|    date|idl|  type|amount|totalcredit|totaldebit|
//+---+-----+-------+--------+---+------+------+-----------+----------+
//|145| 4513|  30095|11272020|  0| debit|  4000|          0|      5000|
//|145| 4514|  30094|11272020|  0| debit|  1000|          0|      5000|
//|135| 4512|  30096|11272020|  0|credit|  2000|       2000|         0|
//|153| 4512|  30095|11272020| 30| debit|  1000|          0|      2000|
//|153| 4512|  30096|11272020|  0|credit|   200|        700|         0|
//|153| 4512|  30097|11272020|  0| debit|  1000|          0|      2000|
//|153| 4512|  30097|11272020|  0|credit|   500|        700|         0|
//+---+-----+-------+--------+---+------+------+-----------+----------+
```